# How to join data frame in Apache spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two dataframes :

df1

```
uid   text   frequency
11    a      1
12    a      2
12    b      1
```

df2

```
text
a
b
c
d
```

I want to create a data frame something like this :

output df

```
uid  text  frequency
11   a     1
11   b     0
11   c     0
11   d     0
12   a     2
12   b     1
12   c     0
12   d     0
```

I've been using spark-sql to write joins like this :

```
 sqlContext.sql("Select uid,df2.text,frequency from df1  right outer join df2 on df1.text= df2.text")
```

which doesn't return the correct result.

Any suggestions how to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this

```
// Find unique combinations of uid and text
df1.select("uid").distinct.join(df2.distinct)  
  // Left join with df1
  .join(df1, Seq("uid", "text"), "leftouter")
  // Replace missing values with 0
  .withColumn("frequency", coalesce($"frequency", lit(0)))
```

which is roughly equivalent to following SQL:

```sql
WITH tmp AS (SELECT DISTINCT df1.uid, df2.text FROM df1  JOIN df2)
SELECT tmp.uid, tmp.text, COALESCE(df1.frequency, 0) AS frequency
FROM tmp LEFT OUTER JOIN df1
ON tmp.uid = df1.uid AND tmp.text = df1.text
```

Comment: From a performance point of view, the first answer is taking a huge time as compared to the SQL query. Is there any way to improve upon that as I'm using data frames and not tables.

Comment: SQL query on what? If you mean Spark SQL query there is no difference here. Both should evaluate to the same execution plan.